# How to transfer the initial value to the written function？

Tags: matlab

```
theta=[60,100,-50,60,100,-50,-1.5,-0.74,1.5,0,0];
lb=[-500*ones(1,6),-2.25,-3,2,0,0];
ub=[500*ones(1,6),-0.75,0,2.6,0.3,0.2];
problem=createOptimProblem('fmincon','objective',Optim_obj_fun,'x0',theta,'lb',lb,'ub',ub,'options',optimset('Algorithm','SQP','Disp','none'));
gs=GlobalSearch;
[theta_result,f]=run(gs,problem);

%In function.m
function f=Optim_obj_fun(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k);
```

I get the error: `'Insufficient number of parameters entered'`

Comment: You need to pass a function handle, `@Optim_obj_fun`. `Optim_obj_fun` by itself calls the function with no arguments, it’s the same as `Optim_obj_fun()`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/gads/createoptimproblem.html) (emphasis mine):

> Function handle to the objective function. For all solvers except
> lsqnonlin and lsqcurvefit, **the objective function must accept a
> vector x and return a scalar**. [...]

Your function does not accept a single vector `x` but many values. Just change the function so all those values are input as a vector, you can unpack them into variables inside.

You are also missing an `@`, as @Cris Luengo says.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem with your help.

Comment: @Leu consider accepting the answer